# I can't read Excel with Angular2

Tags: excel, angular

I want send Excel with Angular to my Server (SpringBoot). I can't do this.

[Error 500 in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325144/error-500-in-server/51327193#51327193)

So, I thought that my problem maybe is "Angular doesn't read Excel." I am trying read my Excel with Angular and I get error ->

My intention is "If Angular can read the Excel, then I will try send Excel."

Because I am trying send Excel and I can't send...

Then:

In this code:

```
 fileChange(event) {
 
    let file: File = event.files[0];
    let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    let fileType = event.parentElement.id;
    myReader.onloadend = function (e) {

      console.log(myReader.result);

    }
    console.log('fileType' , fileType);
    myReader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

ERROR

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This code I got the ->

[Upload a File and Read Data with FileReader in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843218/getting-data-from-filereader-in-angular-2)

Before I try with this code:

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      this.formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
      console.log('al cambiar file' ,  file);
    }
    console.log(' formdata' ,  this.formData );
    console.log(' fileList' ,  fileList);
    console.log('stack' ,  event.files[0]);
  }
```

result[image]

With this code I get name the File and last modification but I can't get cells of Excel.

Comment: can you show your responseType that you are sending with post mehtod?

Comment: hi, you can see the answer server in my first link the my question.

Comment: instead of  headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data') change  headers.append('Content-Type', 'ResponseContentType.Blob') and try to post

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ml/insert 415 ()    status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Invalid mime type \"ResponseContentType.Blob\": does not contain '/'","path":"/ml/insert"}"

Comment: which version of angular currently are you using?

Comment: the version is 5

Comment: Use httpClienModule for post data

Answer (score 0):

use **'xlsx'** package.

```
npm install xlsx
```